# Reuse template in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Lets say I have a template `default.ctp`, is there anyway that I can use that template for multiple controllers or set it as a fallback template when a template is missing?

Ex: `localhost/users/login/` calls `UsersController->login` which tries finding `login.ctp`. If `login.ctp` is missing can I make it use `default.ctp` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default.ctp is a **layout file** which will be used in all cases unless you specifically instruct not to by :

```
$this->viewBuilder()->layout('');
```

While login.ctp in your example is a **[view](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html) file** for the login action. So, they are not alternatives but partners which combine to display the final output. layout/template will always be there irrespective of the presence of view file. If you don't want to display output using any file. Just write :

```
$this->render(false);
```

or

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

where view file is called only when you specifically call [Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html)::render() method.